# awk ignores line with 0 only

Tags: bash, awk

I don’t know why I can not give only `0` to awk in a direct statement, e.g. if I want to output the square of a number:

```
$ echo 4 | awk '$0=$1*$1'
16

$ echo 3 | awk '$0=$1*$1'
9

$ echo 0 | awk '$0=$1*$1'
```

Why do I get nothing on the last try?

PS. it works if I write `$1` in a bracketed statement:

```
$ echo 0 | awk '{print $1*$1}'
0
```

Comment: Assignments return the left hand side as an argument and 0 evaluates to false, so the default print action is not executed. In the bracketed version you explicitly say to print.

Comment: You could: `echo 0 | awk '($0=$1*$1)||1'` in which case `$1*$1` evaluates to 0 but `||1` ("or true")  would fix that to true value.

Comment: @JamesBrown You could but you could also more simply do `{$0=$1*$1}1`

Comment: @123 Yeah, I didn't say my example made any sense. :D

Comment: I didn’t know it was ignored if the expression was evaluated to false. Thanks for the info and thanks for the tips, they are very helpful.

Comment: It's not ignored, it's false. The body of an awk script is made up of `<condition> { <action> }` statements with the default condition being `true` and the default action being `print $0`. You don't expect `if (0) {print}` to print anything, right, and the `0` in the condition certainly isn't being ignored, it is having an effect. Same thing applies here. You can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: It's not _ignored_. Only if it evaluates to non-false value is the _implicit output_ invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `awk` does not ignore a line with 0.

However, your `awk` command: `$0=$1*$1` does not do what you think.

By default awk prints $0 if there is an statement that evaluates to true (not zero).

So, this will always print $0:

```
awk '1'
```

And this will never print $0:

```
awk '0'
```

To do what you want: to always print $0 after it has been re-calculated, you need to do:

```
awk '{$0=$1*$1; print}'
```

And so:

```
$ echo "0" | awk '{$0=$1*$1; print}'
0

$ echo "2" | awk '{$0=$1*$1; print}'
4
```

Or, without changing the value of $0, do:

```
$ echo "2" | awk '{print $0*$0}'
```

Or (shorter but less readable):

```
$ echo "2" | awk '{$0=$0*$0}1'
4
```

And, even shorter:

```
$ echo "4" | awk '{$0*=$0}1'
16
```

This last awk script is actually composed of two command lines:

```
awk '
     <default pattern> {      $0*=$0      }
             1         { <default action> }
    '
```

Which become, replacing the action by print and the condition by all:

```
awk ' /.*/{$0*=$0}
       1  {print $0}'
```

Both lines are applied to all input lines. For all lines `$0` is changed, and for all input lines a `print $0` is executed.

Comment: It makes sense when awk uses `<condition> { <action> }`, but how does awk interpret `'{$0=$0*$0}1'`? What is the condition/action/etc?

Comment: There is no "etc" in awk - it's entirely conditions and actions. As written your script is `<default condition> { <explicit action> } <explicit condition> { <default action> }` where `<default condition>` is `true`, `<explicit action>` is `$0=$0*$0`, `<explicit condition>` is `1` (which evaluates to `true`), and `<default action>` is `print $0`. You could write it all explicitly as `awk '1{$0=$0*$0} 1{print $0}'`. All is explained in wonderful detail in the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins :-).