# Print 0 with awk while doing arithmetic operation

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file1.txt with below content

```
 value1=value2=value3=server2=150=200=Running=0
 value1=value2=value3=server5=0=100=Running=0
 value1=value2=value3=server3=40=100=Running=0
 value1=value2=value3=server8=175=100=Running=0
 value1=value2=value3=server1=0=100=Running=0
 value1=value2=value3=server7=0=100=Running=0
```

I am doing arithmetic operation between column 5 and column 6 considering equal to(=) as field separator. Code is as below.

```
awk -F "=" '$9=(($5*100/$6))' file1.txt
```

But when I am using above code and appending the result in last column its giving result only where the value is not 0 but I need those rows also where the value is 0. Also I would like to sort the rows in descending order based on the last column value.

Below is the result I am getting

```
vlaue1 value2 value3 server2 150 200 Running 0 75
vlaue1 value2 value3 server3 40 100 Running 0 40
vlaue1 value2 value3 server8 175 200 Running 0 87.5
```

Expected Result is as follows

```
vlaue1 value2 value3 server8 175 200 Running 0 87.5
vlaue1 value2 value3 server2 150 200 Running 0 75
vlaue1 value2 value3 server3 40 100 Running 0 40
value1 value2 value3 server5 0 100 Running 0 0
value1 value2 value3 server1 0 100 Running 0 0
value1 value2 value3 server7 0 100 Running 0 0
```

Please assist me how we can achieve this.

Comment: how about `awk -F "=" '{$9=(($5*100/$6))}1' file1.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly print each line. Also if you want to later sort it, you can use this solution: ["How to numerically sort by last column"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/how-to-numerical-sort-by-last-column). For example:

```
awk -F "=" '{$9=$5*100/$6; print $9" "$0}' file1.txt | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Run it as below. Notice 1 at the end.

```
awk -F "=" '{$9=(($5*100/$6))}1' file.txt|sort -nrk9
```

For explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011942/3423750

Comment: Thank you @Phalgun its printing 0 in each but just not sorting but thanks again that you answered even when not in front of system

Comment: I will update the sorting part later. Most online awk compilers do not allow me to pipe output to sort command.